# Admob shows no text banners anymore

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

On the Admob web interface we selected **text banners** but **unchecked image banners** for our app. This has been working until we updated the SDK tools, build tools, platform tools and SDK platforms. Now, our app shows **only image banners** which we explicitly do not want to get. We did not change any code related to the ad and neither did we modify the Admob settings on the web interface.

To locate the problem, we set up a new test project and went through the [official instructions](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start#creating_a_new_project) on how to set up Admob, step-by-step. Same problem! Here is the resulting code:

Here is the ad **(fragment_ad.xml)**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the test activity **(MainActivity.java)**:

```
package com.example.myadapp;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
            AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

...with the layout file **activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:name="com.example.myadapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myadapp.MainActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, the the app's **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myadapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the **LogCat** we get on an AVD running GoogleAPIs API19:

```
12-31 09:12:26.251: I/Ads(2403): Starting ad request.
12-31 09:12:26.251: I/Ads(2403): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB") to get test ads on this device.
12-31 09:12:26.411: D/gralloc_goldfish(2403): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-31 09:12:26.751: D/dalvikvm(2403): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-96486195.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
12-31 09:12:26.951: D/dalvikvm(2403): DexOpt: --- END 'ads-96486195.jar' (success) ---
12-31 09:12:26.951: D/dalvikvm(2403): DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.myadapp/cache/ads-96486195.jar': unzip in 172ms, rewrite 204ms
12-31 09:12:31.271: D/dalvikvm(2403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 262K, 10% free 3566K/3936K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
12-31 09:12:31.271: I/dalvikvm-heap(2403): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.659MB for 1127532-byte allocation
12-31 09:12:31.291: D/dalvikvm(2403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 4666K/5040K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
12-31 09:12:31.941: I/chromium(2403): [INFO:simple_index_file.cc(397)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
12-31 09:12:33.091: I/Ads(2403): Scheduling ad refresh 30000 milliseconds from now.
12-31 09:12:33.091: I/Ads(2403): Ad finished loading.
```

We are imported the **google-play-services-lib** library to Eclipse as described [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

The problem arises both on Android 4.0 and 4.4, also on the emulator, and both with and without adding the device as a test device using `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice(String deviceId)`

Is anyone facing the same problem?

**EDIT:** As for the test project, sometimes *randomly a text banner does show up*. It seems AdMob does not really care about the customisation done on the web interface...